# How to use class initialize vb6 to connect to SQL server?

Tags: vb6

Anyone can help me how can I do for that variable objusername and objpassword of sub login are recognized by the sub Class_Initialize ? I tried this but it does not work.

```
private cn as ADODB.Connection
private record As ADODB.Recordset

private objusername as variant
private objpassword as variant

Public Sub login(objuser As Variant, objpass As Variant)
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=bdd;User ID=" & objusername & ";Password=" & objpassword & ""
cn.Open
    If cn.State = adStateOpen Then
        MsgBox "welcome", vbOKOnly, "connexion"
    End If
end sub


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
On Error GoTo erreur
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set record = New ADODB.Recordset
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=bdd;User ID='" & objusername & "';Password='" & objpassword & "'"
cn.Open
Exit Sub
erreur:
    If Err.Number = -2147217843 Then
        MsgBox "connection failed"
    End If
End Sub
```

and I call class like this but I have always an error.

```
Private Sub CmdOK_Click()
dim x as class1
set x = new class1
x.Login text1,text2
End Sub
```

How can I solve this.

Answer (score 3):

`Class_Initialize` will execute when you call `new class1`, as that's *before* you call `Login` the code in `Class_Initialize` has no idea what the username and password are.

Connect in `Login` instead:

```
private cn as ADODB.Connection
private record As ADODB.Recordset

private objusername as variant
private objpassword as variant

Public Sub login(objuser As Variant, objpass As Variant)
    objusername = objuser
    objpassword = objpass

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=bdd;User ID=" & objusername & ";Password=" & objpassword & ""
    cn.Open
    ...
end sub 

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
End Sub
```

If you want to connect when you create an instance of `Class1` use a factory function in a module which is the closest workaround for the lack of constructors.

```
public function CreateAndLogin(objuser As Variant, objpass As Variant) as class1
    set CreateAndLogin= new Class1
    CreateAndLogin.login bjuser, objpass
end function
```

called with

```
Dim cls as Class1
set cls = CreateAndLogin(text1, text2)
```

Comment: you can show the code to me in detail please. I have difficulty in speaking English

why the class initialize is empty ? i have a lot of sub and function on the class1 which depends on the class initialize

thank you an advance